# discord.py getttig the url of an image present in an embed sent by an user

Tags: discord.py

Yeah . Question present in the title.How to  get the url of an image present in an embed sent by an user using discord.py.
I tried using this code:

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.channel.id == 787662710787145760:
        try:
            print(message.attachments[0].url)
        except IndexError:
            pass
        await bot.process_commands(message)
```

However only works on images.

Comment: Isn't that what you wanted? The title clearly states "getting the url of an image"

Comment: If I pass in an image,it shows url of the image. However if i pass in an embed containing an image it does now show the url of the image.

Comment: Users cannot send embeds, only bots and webhooks. I'm not sure what you're trying to do

Comment: Ok. Is there a way to copy the url of an embed sent by a bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering to your comment, yes, it is possible to get the url of an embed

```py
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    if message.embeds: # Checking if there are any embeds in the message
        embed = message.embeds[0] # Bots can only send 1 embed at a time, webhooks can multiple
        print(embed.image.url)
```

#### Reference:

- [`Message.embeds`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.embeds)
- [`Embed.image`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.image)

Comment: Well it can if the url is not set in initialization

Comment: I figured it out myself.Its print(embed.image.url)

Comment: I have upvoted your comment but it says - Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.